# How to sum the cells in one column start from certain row to the last row?

Tags: r

[image: this dataframe is df1]

this data frame is df1, and the nrow is not constant so I need something like the length of the data frame to the last row.

```
df1$new <- rowSums(df1[7:nrow(df1)])
```

Comment: Please clarify - do you want `df$new` as a new column in your table - that is, a vector with 30 values?  Or are you just wanting a single value that is the sum of `a` from row 7 to the end?   Your use of `rowSums` looks wrong - you dont want to be summing `Var1`, `Freq` and `a` on each line, do you?

Comment: Do you just need `sum(df1$a[7:nrow(df1)])`?

Comment: Also, since the input is a frequency table, does one need to multiply the values of `a` by `Freq` before taking a `sum()`?